# How to show ACF in a WP_Query loop with 'post_type' => 'product'

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Try to achieve this:
I made a ACF (custom field) in my WooCommerce Product and now I try to get this field shown in my template with this code:

```
 <ul class="products">
    <?php

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
                'field'    => 'name',
                'terms'    => 'grouped',
            ),
        ),
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            $linked_with_items = the_field('linked_with_items');
            the_title('<strong>', '</strong>'); echo '<br />';
            echo $linked_with_items;
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul><!--/.products-->
```

But whatever I try also with get_field() the field does not show in my template.
Can someone help?
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

This is the final code fyi

```
 <?php if( have_rows('catalogue') ): ?>
   <?php
       while( have_rows('catalogue') ): the_row(); // catalogue is the field
       the_sub_field('linked_with_items'); ?>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Just to confirm you have set a value for this new field on your products posts right? what do you get with `var_dump(get_field('linked_with_items'));`?

Comment: NULL is the response I get

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try with this:

```
$linked_with_items  = get_field('linked_with_items', get_the_ID());
```

If that doesn't work, just as a test, you could try to simply loop over posts with a foreach

```
foreach ( $loop->posts as $post ) {
    $linked_with_items  = get_field('linked_with_items', $post->ID);
}
```

If none of those work, please make sure that your product actually have that custom field, double check the ACF field settings (rule section), the field slug, and double check your product edit page to see if the fields shows there.

Comment: Both methods do not work. I think I do something wrong with the loop... cause this loop is inside another loop. I keep on looking

Comment: Please try to var_dump($post->ID); in the second solution and the lookup in the database if the acf_field is actually present and saved. Or do the other way around, find a post with that acf_field surely saved and then use it hardcode (just as a test) to see if the get_field is working for you

Comment: Indeed then you'll see int(304) int(270) int(193) int(19) int(13) int(6)

Comment: Ok, now use those id, search into the wp_postmeta table and look if any of those have "linked_with_items" as one of their postmeta rows with an actual value

Comment: thanks that did my mind went in the right direction! linked_with_items was not a field but a sub field inside a field stupid me

Comment: ahahah jeez how this job sometimes make you spend a lot of time for foolish issues :D good it is all set now !